# What is more efficient in this case - Has many through or has many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I have 3 models:

User, Page, Photos

Photos belong to a page, and a page (they only have one) belongs to a user. However one of my navigation links will be for a url showing all photos that a user has submitted (will be used often) - what would be the best, most efficient association to use or go about it?

```
class User
  has_many :pages
  has_many :photos, :through => :pages
end
```

So a foreign key for user_id in pages, and one for pages_id in photos (Which will mean I can get the user photos by @user.page.photos - or use 'includes' to make it more efficient - but is it still better than below?)

```
class User
  has_many :pages
  has_many :photos
end
```

So a foreign key for user_id in pages, and one for pages_id and user_id in photos. (Which will mean I can directly call @user.photos)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be most efficient for the second example. This is because you won't have to joins through an intermediary table to find the photos for the user.

The `photos` table then would be storing both the `page_id` and the `user_id` foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was thinking too but wanted to check with someone more experienced than me :)

Comment: he was looking for dat 62.1k